# Jquery Tabs not working properly

Tags: jquery

I am new to jquery. I am using jquery tab , but facing some problems.

My requirement is : When i click on tab1, it should open tab1.php(By default)
                    when i click on tab2, it should open tab2.php, etc.

But its not working properly. can anyone please help me here?

Below is my code :

Tab1.php

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
        <head>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
            <title>jQuery UI Example Page</title>

  <link  href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>

    <script> 
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#example').tabs();                
    });
    </script>
    </head>

    <body>

    <div id="example">
         <ul>
             <li><a href="tab1.php"><span>Content 1</span></a></li>
             <li><a href="tab2.php"><span>Content 2</span></a></li>

         </ul>
    </div>
         <h1> tab1 </h1>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Tab2.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
        <title>jQuery UI Example Page</title>

<link  href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<script> 
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').tabs();                
});
</script>
</head>

<body>

<div id="example">
     <ul>
         <li><a href="tab1.php"><span>Content 1</span></a></li>
         <li><a href="tab2.php"><span>Content 2</span></a></li>
     </ul>
</div>
<h1> tab2 </h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you mean inside each tab to open an iframe of the tabxxx.php , or you just want a link that open a new page on the tab header?

Comment: I think it should work, have you check in `console` what the `error` is?

Comment: @MaVRoSCy : I think i needed to add few more things for better understanding.I have updated my question with respective php files.Can you check and let me know if you need some more info from me?.

Answer (score 2):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#showPageContent').load('tab.php');
    $('#example').tabs({
        select: function(event, ui) {
       $('#showPageContent').load($(ui.tab).attr('shpwpage'));
    }

    });                 
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Ha8Gh/18/)**

Comment: Hi Sam,Thanks for the quick help. But when i open the tab.php in browser,it shows contents of tab.php twice. For your info, i am attachning screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
$("#example").tabs({
    select: function(event, ui) {
       window.location = $.data(ui.tab, 'href.tabs');
       $("#example").tabs("url" , indexOfTheTab , newUrl );
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi Shree, I tried your solution. It worked , but i need to click on tabs many times to navigate to another tab. And also, my Url is not changing when i click on Tab2.

Comment: can you suggest some other solution?

Comment: Hi Shree, i am troubling you too much. But kindly help me. i have edited my initial question and posted my both the php files (tab1.php and tab2.php) .

can you please check code in request and suggest code changes required as per my requirement?

Answer (score 0):

I have made some changes to your html so that this example can work:

```
<div id="example">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#" url="http://www.example.com"><span>Example</span> </a> </li>
        <li><a href="#" url="http://www.ebay.com"><span>Ebay</span></a> </li>
        <li><a href="#" url="http://www.jquery.com"><span>JQuery</span></a></li>
    </ul>
    <iframe id="showPageContent" src="" style="width:100%;border:0px;height:300px;"></iframe>
</div>
```

Check out a working [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Ha8Gh/23/)

Basically I have created an iframe that will be used to load the different pages

```
<iframe id="showPageContent" src="" style="width:100%;border:0px;height:300px;"></iframe>
```

And then on document ready, I have added an `onchange` handler to load the URL attibute of the selected tab

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var firstLoad=1;
    var tabs = $('#example').tabs({
        activate: function (event, ui) {

            var active = $("#example").tabs("option", "active");
            var url = $("#example ul>li a").eq(active).attr('url');
            $('#showPageContent').attr('src', url);

        },
        load: function (event, ui) {
            if(firstLoad==1){
                var url = $("#example ul>li a").first().attr('url');
                $('#showPageContent').attr('src', url);
                firstLoad=0;
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Also the first load is handled in the `load()` function